# Applying django-filter settings

Tags: django, django-settings, django-filters

From [django-filter documentation](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ref/settings.html) I can see that there is a setting to disable the empty choice under heading [FILTERS_EMPTY_CHOICE_LABEL](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ref/settings.html#filters-empty-choice-label). I am attempting to apply that setting however cannot get the the correct syntax.

In my settings.py file I have attempted to use (likely incorrect syntax):

```
EMPTY_CHOICE_LABEL = [
    {
        'ChoiceFilter.empty_label': 'None'
    }
]
```

In comparison, [django-guid](https://django-guid.readthedocs.io/en/latest/settings.html) has a good example on how to apply relevant setting in the settings.py file:

```
DJANGO_GUID = {
    'GUID_HEADER_NAME': 'Correlation-ID',
    'VALIDATE_GUID': True,
    'RETURN_HEADER': True,
    'EXPOSE_HEADER': True,
    'INTEGRATIONS': [],
    'UUID_LENGTH': 32,
}
```

What is the correct syntax to apply the setting.py file in the case of `django-filter` settings?

Answer (score 0):

This error trace says that you are using a variable named `FILTERS_`, which is not defined.
My suggestion is to look for occurrences of `FILTERS_` in your code base.

Could you please post the full error trace?

Answer (score 0):

Apologies, I took the documentation to update the settings.py file however this setting can be applied as shown in the example below in `empty_label`:

```
class MyFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):

    name = django_filters.AllValuesFilter(empty_label=None, field_name='name')
    class Meta:
        model = SomeModel

        fields = ['name']
```